# How to benchmark huge bounded vectors?

Tags: pallet, storage, benchmarking, benchmark, boundedvec

I want to have a queue system in a pallet using a storage value and a bounded vector.

```rust
/// Data related to tranmission queues.
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn at_block_queue)]
pub type AtBlockQueue<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, Queue<T::BlockNumber, T::SimultaneousTransmissionLimit>, ValueQuery>;
```

```rust
pub struct Queue<BlockNumber: Clone + PartialEq + Debug + sp_std::cmp::PartialOrd, Limit: Get<u32>>(
    pub BoundedVec<(NFTId, BlockNumber), Limit>,
);
```

I would like this queue to be limited at 10_000_000 values. This seems ok while testing but the benchmarks are failing due to a failed allocation.

In my benchmarking code, I use a function to fill the queue to simulate usage :

```rust
// Benchmark / tests only
    pub fn bulk_insert(
        &mut self,
        nft_id: NFTId,
        block_number: BlockNumber,
        number: u32,
    ) -> Result<(), ()> {
        self.0.try_extend(vec![(nft_id, block_number); number as usize].into_iter())
    }
```

I was wondering if the Limit value was too high or my benchmarking method is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10M entries of `u32` in a vector? Sure this will not fit in the memory of the runtime, which is capped at 32 MiB.

Three things to consider: It looks like your data structure is rather a map. Then instead of going for `StorageValue<Vec<` which should only be the last resort, you could try out `StorageDoubleMap` which maps `NFTId x BlockNumber` to `Limit`. Then you can have theoretically unlimited number of entries.

Other thing is that depending on what you mean by "queue" you could try to use the [`Message Queue`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/3bc3742d5c0c5269353d7809d9f8f91104a93273/frame/message-queue/src/lib.rs#L18) pallet, which can be used to enqueue and later-on process messages in a PoV-safe way.

Last thing is that even *if* the 10M entries would go through the benchmark, the resulting PoV would be to large to deploy onto any para-chain. Currently para-chains are capped to 5MiB Proof size per block. Accessing that storage value would consume at least 40MiB in the worst case.

Comment: Understood, thank you taking the time to answer.